# Parsing problems of vDDDTypes data with icalendar in python

Tags: python, datetime, icalendar, decoding

as you may understand from the following I'm not a very skilled programmer. Nevertheless I'm trying to write a python program for importing and storing in a database data from an icalendar formatted file. The file has several occurrences like the following one (skipping the non relevant info):

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:TU1586072026
DTSTAMP:20240125T161430Z
SUMMARY:My meeting
DESCRIPTION:None
...
CREATED:20231004T161313Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20231023T162939Z
END:VEVENT
```

My problem is in the decoding of the LAST-MODIFIED value.

If I run:

```
    print("dtstamp: " + str(component.get('dtstamp').dt))
    print("created: " + str(component.get('created').dt))
    print("modified: " + str(component.get('last-modified').dt))
```

I get an error after it prints the first two in a proper way:

```
dtstamp: 2024-01-25 16:14:30+00:00
created: 2023-10-04 16:13:13+00:00

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sailslack/Coding/Python/PIM/cal_import.py", line 97, in ical_import
    print("modified: " + str(component.get('last-modified').dt))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

While, if I don't use the .dt attribute in the last line:

```
    print("dtstamp: " + str(component.get('dtstamp').dt))
    print("created: " + str(component.get('created').dt))
    print("modified: " + str(component.get('last-modified')))
```

I get no errors, but:

```
    dtstamp: 2024-01-25 16:14:30+00:00
    created: 2023-10-04 16:13:13+00:00
    modified: vDDDTypes(2023-10-23 16:29:39+00:00, Parameters({}))
```

looking exactly like I should use the .dt attribute as for the others.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**: This example works on my python environment, now with try block to handle missing components:

```
from icalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime

with open('iCalendar.ics', 'rb') as e:
    ecal = Calendar.from_ical(e.read())
    for component in ecal.walk():
        if component.name == 'VEVENT':
            print(component.name)
            com_attr = ['CREATED','DTSTAMP','LAST-MODIFIED']
            for timing in com_attr:
                try:
                    print(f"{timing}: {component.get(timing).dt}")
                except AttributeError:
                    print(f"{timing} -> does not exist!")
            com_text = ['UID','SUMMARY','DESCRIPTION']
            for tex in com_text:
                try:
                    print(f"{tex}: {component.get(tex)}")                    
                except AttributeError:
                    print(f"{tex} -> does not exist!")
```

Output, if e.g. last-modified is missing:

```
VEVENT
CREATED: 2023-10-04 16:13:13+00:00
DTSTAMP: 2024-01-25 16:14:30+00:00
LAST-MODIFIED -> does not exist!
UID: TU1586072026
SUMMARY: My meeting
DESCRIPTION: None
```

Comment: Great job @Hermann12. It works with a  check for presence of LAST-UPDATED otherwise when the field is not present it throws an error. Thanks again.

Comment: @sailslack, I added a try block see my updated answer.